# Why R dataframe export to SQL Server does not work?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I try to push an R table to an SQL Server database, here my script:

```r
dbWriteTable(con, 
             name = "ci_d", 
             value = ci_d, 
             field.types = c(`thing`="varchar(3000)",
                             `notes`="varchar(3000)"
             )
```

and the error message :

> Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) :
> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 22001: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver]Troncation à droite de la chaîne de données

Google translation from French: `"Right truncation of the data string"`

Anyone has an idea to solve this ?

Comment: This is common when the length of the string in the database table is not sufficient to handle this data. You can query `"select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name='ci_d'"` to see what types (e.g., `char, `nchar`, `varchar`, vs `nvarchar`) and max string length the DBMS thinks the columns should have.

Comment: Thanks, I should use varchar(max) in field.types thing.

Comment: I wasn't saying that, I was suggesting you need to find out what the database thinks that `ci_d` has for column types and size limitations. But if it works, congrats. Is this a new table (created here), or does it exist and you're overwriting it?

Comment: It's a new table. To overwrite I need to write overwrite=True. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Related, possible duplicate, explanation of the error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/183488/680068